# How does heredity work with Endogenous retrovirus?

Tags: genetics, evolution, retrovirus

Q1: If someone in a species gets infected with an endogenous retrovirus, does that mean that absolutely all of their children will have that endogenous retrovirus? Or is it based on chance?

Q2: is there such a thing as an allele for the virus being there, and for it not being there? How does it work?

Q3: how can an endogenous retrovirus disappear from a species? And when it cannot disappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a [provirus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provirus) to be heritable, the infection must occur in the germ line. The initial integration would occur at one site in the genome and thus the locus could be described as [hemizygous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zygosity#Hemizygous). Inheritance would indeed be probabilistic, depending on whether an offspring inherits the provirus-containing chromosome or its uninfected homolog.

Eventually, the endogenous retrovirus (ERV) can become [fixed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixation_(population_genetics)) or lost in a population by genetic drift and natural selection. Additionally, [retrotransposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrotransposon) and, more importantly, reinfection can greatly increase copy number and allow ERV persistence despite a lack of fixation at specific loci. It should also be noted that more recently acquired ERVs exist that have not reached fixation in humans.

---

**References and Further Reading:**

[Boeke JD, Stoye JP. Retrotransposons, Endogenous Retroviruses, and the Evolution of Retroelements. In: Coffin JM, Hughes SH, Varmus HE, editors. Retroviruses. Cold Spring Harbor (NY): Cold Spring Harbor Laboratory Press; 1997.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK19468/#!po=5.55556)

[Belshaw R, Pereira V, Katzourakis A, Talbot G, Pačes J, Burt A, Tristem M. 2004. Long-term reinfection of the human genome by endogenous retroviruses. Proc Nat Acad Sci 101(14):4894–4899.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC387345/)